# Quando devo usar cada nível de log no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, log, ide

Existem diferentes níveis de *log* no Android Studio, que talvez, digo talvez, não seja muito diferente em outras IDE's. Basicamente são as maneira diferentes de como posso gravar uma mensagem no *logcat*. Os tipos são `VERBOSE`,`DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR` e `ASSERT`.

O que significa cada um desses? Em quais situações devo usa-los?

Comment: aqui nesse link que abri pressionando a ajuda do android studio:
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: feito, @Ack Lay, se quiser, seria interessante para min (rerere) marcar a resposta como correta.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o site oficial de ajuda do android studio, https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html, segue traduzido:

No menu Nível de registro, selecione um dos seguintes valores:

- Verbose - Mostra todas as mensagens de log (o padrão).
- Debug - Mostra mensagens de log de depuração que são úteis apenas durante o desenvolvimento, bem como os níveis de mensagem mais baixos nesta lista.
- Info - Mostra as mensagens de log esperadas para uso regular, bem como os níveis de mensagem mais baixos nesta lista.
- Avisar - Mostra possíveis problemas que ainda não são erros, bem como os níveis de mensagem inferior nesta lista.
- Erro - Mostra problemas que causaram erros, bem como o nível de mensagem inferior nesta lista.
- Assert - Mostra problemas que o desenvolvedor espera que nunca aconteçam.

é isso...